# How can I share the common object between components?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I want to share my main object between components in Angular project.

My main component is a Map component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  template: `<div id="map"></div>`
})
export class MapComponent {

  map: Map;

  constructor() {
    this.map = new Map({});
  }

}
```

The `map` object of `MapComponent` will be use in other components.

`MapControlComponent` will add an object in `map` object. `MapControlComponent` has not a view.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-control',
  template: ``
})
export class MapControlComponent {

  constructor() {
    var control = new MapControl();

    // Following object will be add in map object in MapComponent.
    // map.controls.add(control);
  }

}
```

and usage will be like this:

```
<app-map>
    <app-map-control></app-map-control>
<app-map>
```

But also I should use multiple times as following.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="map1">
        <app-map>
            <app-map-control></app-map-control>
        <app-map>
    </div>

    <div id="map2">
        <app-map>
            <app-map-control></app-map-control>
        <app-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Naturally all map object is different from another.)

But I could not decide how to share map object in MapComponent. 
I can also have components other than the MapControlComponent that use map object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to grasp the concepts and best practices in Angular.

First things first : [to communicate between components](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), you should use a service.

But in your case, [the component is supposed to hold the view's logic](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#put-presentation-logic-in-the-component-class).

For the other component, [a component is supposed to have a view](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components), otherwise it's just another Angular feature (all but a component).

What I would advise you, in terms of reusability and best practices, would be to make a service that **creates a new control for a given map**. The signature would be

```
createControl(map: Map): MapControl {}
```

You would also attach it to the map :

```
addControlToMap(control: MapControl, map: Map): void {}
```

With this process, your services abstracts the map logic (meaning your component gets "dumb", in the sens that if you change your map library, you will only have to change the service and give the same implementation), and the components keeps its code clean and short. You also respect the best practices offered by Angular, which increases your code reusability and easyness to read.

Comment: I am not so clear for your solution. Where to create the map object and map. You said that to create MapControl object.

Comment: The map object should be in the component. The map control object should not be declared anywhere but should instead be created and returned in a function.